# Return extra data with CollectionResponse in Cloud Endpoints (google app engine)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

How can you return some extra data with the CollectionResponse in Cloud Endpoints?

For example, you can do this:

```
return CollectionResponse.<MyEntity>builder().setItems(MyEntityList).setNextPageToken(queryIterator.getCursor().toWebSafeString()).build();
```

which will append the following to your json CollectionResponse:

```
"nextPageToken": "XlcFEgoLY3JlYXR123hdGUSBwiJxJK8oiwefgoTc35vbmUtZ29hbC0yMTcyODDFE$IiCxIEVXNlchiAgIA-JaVCgwLEgRHb2FsGICAwefggIAKDBgAIAE"
```

But can I specify something of my own?

Answer (score 0):

If you need more data, simply extend the class or define your own. There's nothing particularly special about `CollectionResponse`.

Comment: Well the extra data is relevant to the entire response - not to every entity. I don't want it to be part of the CollectionResponse, but have it be higher up the json chain somewhere - similar to where the nextPageToken shows up